# HTTP: 204 No Content Header

Tags: domain, http, seo, http-headers

I just registered a new domain and at the moment it sends a 403.

Is the HTTP-Header "204 No Content" a good header for a domain
with no content at the moment,
because I'm working on the site and the domain will be a while blank
and want no bad SEO-Startup ;) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that from the SEO perspective no content is no content. Whether you send that status code or deliver an empty HTML page I think you would see the same SEO results. Is this a new domain name (i.e. with no previous history)? If so it may not even get indexed by any search engines so it may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on SEO, but the typical use of the 204 response is to not refresh the current page.  It's probably most appropriate with a request other than GET (like POST or DELETE):

Excerpt from [HTTP/1.1: Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.